# Working wity OpenLayers maps Tutorial "Quick Start" I received the following error message attached

Tags: openlayers

I started working with OpenLayers.org "Quick Start online tutorial", I received the following error defined in the attached screen shot.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`>npn start
npn should be run outside of the Node.js REPL, in your normal shell.
<Press Ctrl+D to exit.>
>
```

I begin the tutorial with Node.js as the required program to start the coding process?

What is the recommended program to use with OpenLayers online Learn More Quick Start to work with the online tutorials?

Comment: Please double-check the command you typed. It's `npm start`, not `>npn start`.